# Where can I find some good 2-person strategies/tips for Halloween Spooktacular on Insane?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I'm struggling with Spooktacular on Insane, and I was wondering if anyone had any tips, or knew of any guides. The only guide I've seen is pre-7.07 and no longer works due to the squire nerf.

Usually I only play with my boyfriend, so we only have 2 people in the game, so I am ideally looking for strategies that would work with only 2 people in the game.

**Edit**

We've come close to beating it with a combination of Monk Electric, Strength Drain, and Ensnare auras for DPS, Mage Fireball towers for lightening immunes, and Squire SliceNDice at a few chokes, but we can't complete the final Mini Ogre wave, even with everything healed up. The rest of it has gotten fairly easy.

The biggest problem is there are only 2 of us, and 3 crystals to defend, and the mini ogres just walk through our squire towers, even w/ strength drain active. SliceNDice have 9k hp, and we tried with spike blockades which have over 12k. We just can't be everywhere at once, especially with the assassians all over us. We've managed to make  it to the last 100 enemies but a crystal always falls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I do to beat it on insane:

Required:
1 Tower Squire
1 Tower Monk
As many DPS huntresses as possible (it helps if the squire/monk can swap to dps huntress).

Optional:
Tower Wizard (great for repairs and mage towers)

The main things you need to watch out for are the kobolds, ogres, and wyverns, and since there is a very limited amount of DU, you have to maintain a fine balance at all three crystal positions, which can be difficult.

Here is the typical setup I like to use when doing the mission on both hard and insane:

[image: Initial Setup]

This setup uses the exact amount of initial mana available.  My monk's aura are quite large in radius, bigger than the circles show, but the positions should be what they are.   The only things missing from this setup are the remaining defenses used to defend the crystals.  This depends entirely on how many people you have and where you will position them.

[image: Completed Setup]

This setup puts a decent amount of defence at each crystal, but you'll want to shift things around depending on if you have 2 people (can only cover 2 places) or more (put towers at the center where most of the enemies gather).

Easy to miss defenses on that picture:

- Spinner on top of building
- Barricade by right crystal
- Bouncer on bottom invisible path near bottom crystal

**Crystal Defence**

The middle crystal is by far the most difficult to defend.  It is pretty much attacked from all sides by both wyverns and ogres.  Put your best DPS ranged character here.  They will be busy for most of the fight fending off all sides.

The top crystal is the second hardest to defend due to the extremely short path wyverns have to take to get to the crystal (they flight straight out of the door).  Also, that north door tend to spawn lots of ogres.  Put your second best DPS character here.

If you have more friends, the next part will help a lot.  The right side can pretty much handle itself unless a mini ogre pop out of the spawn point in the middle of the map.  At that point, you'll want someone there to take care of them before the barricades there breaks.

Finally, having a person run around the map to repair and upgrade is a huge bonus.

**Threats**

In later rounds (10-11) kobolds are your biggest threat.  They come in large packs and can easily take down a fully upgraded bouncer in a few explosions.  ***When placing your traps. make sure that you place the towers back enough from the walls so the explosions do not damage them.***

Mini ogres are also really annoying, having a ton of health along with their usual ogre splash ball attack.  Take them out as soon as possible.

Wyverns are your biggest threat, it helps a lot if each person guarding the crystal has a strong attacking pet that can take out wyverns while you focus on clearing the lanes of enemies.

Here are the 2 links to the pictures as I cant' get the top one to size properly so its too small to see:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXD58.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzYF7.jpg

**Update in response to comments**

The problem with crystal trackers is they are great aoe, but their range is more limited than other weapons and their DPS is not as good.  It would help a lot if at least one of you switched over to a more DPS oriented weapon for the mini ogres.  Again, doing the challenge on hard would score you a van wolfenstein, a nice one (3-4 split 30+ upgrades, fast reload/shoot) will make quick work of the mini ogres.  The best part is their range is very long, you can easily reach the barricades next to the top left crystal while standing near the bottom middle crystal to take out any mini ogres that are encroaching on that area.  Generally enemies from the middle spawn will not go up that ramp towards the right crystal.  They tend to come up the south ramp towards the bottom crystal instead.  The only enemies that go in the other direction are the mini ogres.

As for the assassins, make sure you are using Huntress Animus pets, they will not only take care of incoming assassins but can easily handle any wyverns coming at the crystal you are defending as well, leaving you to handle the more important areas.

In summary, this is not really a challenge that you can expect to do with less than 3 people, I believe it is designed like that on purpose as the rewards you receive are quite good.  One last thing you can try is completely overloading the right crystal (put at least 5 strike towers there for the mini ogres) and just use barricades on the other 2 crystals for defense.

Comment: I can't seem to get the top picture to size properly.

Comment: We tried using squire towers and they died to fast... there's only two of us to help defend 3 crystals, so I think thats our biggest problem. We can get to the final wave using mostly monk auras and mage towers for damage, and squire blockades in a few choke points for added defense, but the final mini ogres wave destorys us.... if we had a 3rd person it'd be easy.

Comment: @Rachel sounds to me like you didn't have enough barriers in place or have high enough DPS to take out those mini ogres.  The Von Wolfenstein you get from doing halloween on hard with a huntress is an excellent weapon for DPS purposes.

Comment: We both have some fully-upgraded Crystal Trackers which we use, but I don't see your setup working with only 2 people. For example, you only have a single barricade between the corner crystal and the new spawn point in the middle. That won't hold on Insane without a DPS there to back it up. Our tower squire has 9k hp SliceNDice and we put one of those, a Fireball tower, ele aura, strengh drain, and ensnare at that choke and it will STILL go down without a bit of intervention in some waves.

Answer (score 0):

We had very few bumpers - pretty much every place there's enemies walking up a staircase, if you put one or two bowling balls and a slow aura, they will be self-sufficient for the entire game (just make sure to upgrade/heal the auras - upgrading towers is more-or-less useless).  Make sure the squire has high tower-attack, and the monk has high everything-tower.

This will take care of literally everything but the two invisible pathways and air.  The invisible-pathways can be dealt-with with a bumper, slow-aura, and strength-drain aura; and the air can be dealt with using lots of arrow-towers.

Then the only things you really need to kill are the jumping ninja-dudes.  You spend the rest of your time running around heal auras, and alt+tabbed out waiting for the ridiculously-long rounds to end.

Comment: ever since the update the amount of enemies have drastically been reduced in the halloween challenge.  So I wouldn't consider them ridiculously long. 2000 enemies in the final round isn't that bad compared to 8000 from before.  I really doubt you'll be able to afk insane now, especially with the buffed damage.

Comment: @yx: Haven't tried it since then, but no matter how much damage or hp the enemy had, it never really mattered, except for air/ogres - everything else never even made it up the stairs, thanks to the bowling balls (+slow auras) pushing them back down.

Answer (score 0):

We two manned it with inferno trap + lightning aura + ensnare aura at each spawn, with two MM per crystal (aimed at the crystal), and one spike barricade to block off each possible ogre spawn, with a str drain on top.  The trick is to press shift a lot and run to ogre spawns.  Given that with a semi-decent VW, and even more so with a sicarius, you can kill an ogre in a couple seconds, it's very doable with two.

Answer (score 0):

We beated Spooktacular on Insane with a Huntress (Tower Build; 100-100-50-50) and Huntress (DPS Build; 40k DPS). The base trap layout is that every crystal is defended by 2 Proximity Mine Trap, 1 Gas Trap and 1 Ethereal Spike Trap. More traps will get added near the spawns and in their paths to the crystals (we used the combination of Proximity Mine, Gas and Ethereal Spike Trap). So at least every Ogre will get hit by at least 4 traps before he get even near to a crystal. In the attack waves the DPS Build Huntress stays on the Roof and protects primary the 2 crystals nearby with focus on Ogres and Wyvern. The Tower Build Huntress stays near the other crystal. In the last waves you can say that all pathes are spammed with damage dealing traps.